# SQL join multiple keys multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to join 2 tables and am having trouble determining the correct syntax for my query. I have a single table containing faults which references an asset table. The reference to the asset table exists twice though. Once for the asset which is actually defective and once for the primary asset to which the defective asset belongs.

Here's a simplified version of my table structure.

**Table Faults**

**int** faultId

**int** faultedAssetId

**int** faultedPrimaryAssetId

**Table Assets**

**int** assetId

**varchar** assetName

In my query I'd like to end up with the following columns

faultId

faultedAssetId

faultedAssetName

faultedPrimaryAssetId

faultedPrimaryAssetName

I currently have the tables joined on the faultedAssetId and am able to retrieve assetName from the Assets table as faultedAssetName but I can't figure out how to join again and retrieve the assetName column for the faultedPrimaryAssetId as faultedPrimaryAssetName.

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can identify two table with table alias.

```
SELECT 
    tf.faultId,
    tf.faultedAssetId,
    ta1.assetName AS faultedAssetName,
    tf.faultedPrimaryAssetId,
    ta2.assetName AS faultedPrimaryAssetName
FROM faults tf
LEFT JOIN assets ta1 ON ta1.assetId = tf.faultedAssetId
LEFT JOIN assets ta2 ON ta2.assetId = tf.faultedPrimaryAssetId
```